# PropertyDescriptor and Attributes

Tags: c#, properties, propertygrid, propertydescriptor

I have inherited the `PropertyDescriptor` class to provide kind of 'dynamic' properties. I'm adding some attributes to the PropertyDescriptor. This works perfectly.

When displaying a object in a `PropertyGrid`, the `ReadOnlyAttribute` works, but the `EditorAttribute` doesn't work!

```
internal class ParameterDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor {
    //...
    public ParameterDescriptor(/* ... */) {
        List<Attribute> a = new List<Attribute>();
        string editor = "System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor,System.Design";
        //...
        a.Add(new ReadOnlyAttribute(true));                         // works
        a.Add(new DescriptionAttribute("text"));                    // works
        a.Add(new EditorAttribute(editor, typeof(UITypeEditor)));   // doesn't work!
        //...    
        this.AttributeArray = a.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The object that is displayed uses a inherited `TypeConverter`:

```
public class ParameterBoxTypeConverter: TypeConverter {
    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes) {
        List<PropertyDescriptor> desc = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        //...
        ParameterDescriptor d = new ParameterDescriptor(/* ... */);
        desc.Add(d);
        //....
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(desc.ToArray());
    }
```

I'm stuck, because the `PropertyGrid` simply isn't showing anything (I expected a "..." at the property value). And it seems there's no way to debug!

So how can I find what's wrong here?
Is there a way to debug into the PropertyGrid, etc?

Comment: You don't show what you then *do* with `a`... are you passing this into the base ctor? or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a few quick tests, the name needs to be fuly qualified:

```
const string name = "System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
attribs.Add(new EditorAttribute(name, typeof(UITypeEditor)));
```

Internally, it uses `Type.GetType`, and:

```
var type1 = Type.GetType("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
// ^^^ not null
var type2 = Type.GetType("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design");
// ^^^ null
```

Of course, you could just use:

```
attribs.Add(new EditorAttribute(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)));
```

Alternatively, you can `override GetEditor` and do whatever your want.

Comment: Good point. Finally I cannot use the overload `new EditorAttribute(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))` for some reasons. How did you find out `Internally, it uses Type.GetType`???

Comment: @joe are you missing a reference to `System.Design.dll` ? I've checked, and it has been declared as `public` since 2.0, so it should work fine. What message do you get? Re the latter: I opened it in reflector. I *could* also have used the public debugging symbols download, but reflector is more convenient for me.

Comment: @joe for info, the method responsible here is `PropertyDescriptor.GetTypeFromName`; unfortunately, while it is `protected`, it is not `virtual`, so you can't `override` just that

Comment: I've also checked the references, all fine. Calling `GetTypeFromName("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor")` form inside of the `PropertyDescriptor` returns also null.

Comment: It turns out that both `Type.GetType` and `PropertyDescriptor.GetTypeFromName` requires the fully-qualified name. I assumed that name and dll reaches out here, but it doesn't. So I have to find out how to achieve this. Thanks so far.

Comment: @joe interesting aside: if the type doesn't resolve first time, it checks for `ComponentType` - if that is non-null, it retries using the assembly from the `ComponentType` as a hint